# Kubernetes AWS Fargate (EKS) continuously terminating pod hosting React service

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, aws-fargate, aws-application-load-balancer

I am using AWS EKS (managed Kubernetes service) and Fargate (managed nodes) to deploy a pod running a nodejs React service on port 5000. The pod switches from "Running" state to "Terminating" state continuously immediately after deployment to Fargate. Eventually, it settles on "Running". Other pods are running fine on Fargate.

I am unable to view the logs due to Kubernetes reporting `net/http: TLS handshake timeout` .

The service is fronted by AWS Application Load Balancer (ALB). In the target group, I can see continuous registration and deregistration of the pod/node IP.

How can I troubleshoot this further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the React service was taking a long time to start due the compute allocation 0.25 vCPU and 0.5 GB, and eventually failing after 10 minutes. We set the following resource requests and limits in the deployment manifest. The pod starts within a couple of minutes without problems.

```
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 1000m
              memory: 2000Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 800m
              memory: 1500Mi
```

Answer (score 1):

Some ways to troubleshoot:

- With kubectl, if your pods are run with a K8s deployment:

  ```sh
  kubectl describe deployment <deployment-name>  check for events
  ```
- With kubectl, before the pod goes into Terminating

  ```sh
  kubectl logs <pod-id>
  kubectl describe pod <pod-id>  check for events
  ```
- Check EKS control plane logs in the S3 bucket where you are sending them to.

The idea is here is to troubleshoot with the Kubernetes tools.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. `kubectl describe` doesn't provide much information other than scaled up and scaled down events. `kubectl logs` times out and returns TLS handshake message indicating the pod doesn't exist even though the status is "Running". It seems to me the pod isn't fully starting up or takes a while to start, and during that time `kubectl log` and `kubectl exec` are not possible.

Comment: Does your pod/container run at all locally?